# Is there enough information to know what this regex is searching and replacing?

Tags: regex, search, replace

Could anyone explain what's being replaced here?

I don't know if enough information is present to understand what's being searched and what's being replaced:

```
    regEx.Pattern = "(\s) *(\S)"
    regEx.Global = True
    that = regEx.Replace(that, "$1$2")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\s` is a whitespace character, such as a tab or a space. `\S` is any other character. So this preserves the first whitespace character and strips out all following spaces (specifically spaces, not any whitespace character) that occur before a printing character. I'm guessing maybe it's to "clean" lines that use both tab and space indentation, though this seems like a pretty lousy way to do that.

Comment: Thanks. Does the "$1$2" syntax refer to arguments that are supposed to be coming from somewhere else in the program?

Comment: `\s` also matches `\n` and `\r` and probably other whitespace characters (like vertical tab).

Comment: Hugo, $1 and so on refer to capturing groups in the regex. In this case, (\s) is $1, and (\S) is $2.